# Layout issue with Micromax Fun book (Size qualifiers confusion)

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have the following structure of layouts for a particular activity:

[image]

Now when I check the specs of Micromax Funbook over [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_funbook_p300-4701.php) I get to know it is a 7 inch tab with resolution of 400X800

The docs state that for seven inches tablest I should use sw-600dp qualifier. However I am puzzled as the concerend tablet is taking layouts from sw-480dp folder.

When I test on a Nexus 5 device which is 4.95 inches and thus should either refer to sw-480 or sw-600 I see it takes the layout from layout folder without any size qualifier(mock_layout.xml - without qualifiers)

What could be wrong? What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I have the same issue in eclipse ,fixed by making `layout-large-mdpi` i fixed it

Comment: I am working above API 14 (So essentially the rules for 3.2 version and above apply for me) Which means I cannot be using layout-large or similar qualifiers.

Comment: of coarse you can make.just try it. but i am telling you about Eclipse only.If you are working in studio i have not idea.

Comment: This technique is IDE-platform independent brother :)